# Serializing a proxy object to access a remote servlet

Tags: java, servlets, rmi

I'm trying to write a proxy for invocation of a remote servlet object from a local HttpServlet container in Java and I am somehow stuck with the Howtos.

At the very first step, I tried to write an interface that extends both Servlet and Remote so that on the server side I can register it with my servlet container and use it as the proxy to serialize the calls to the servlet object resided on the client. Something like the following code:

```
public interface IServletRemote extends Remote, Servlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws RemoteException;

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws RemoteException;

    public void init() throws RemoteException;

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException, RemoteException;

    public void destroy() throws RemoteException;
}
```

I can't go past building the interface because the above code results in the following error which is reasonable knowing the polymorphism / inheritance constraints of Java:

*RemoteException is not compatible with throws clause in Servlet.init(ServletConfig)*

I am not completeley sure whether/how I can find a solution to the remote invocation of a servlet object from a local servlet container. In other words, I wonder if what I am trying to achieve is feasible considering the serialization requirements for HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, etc?

Any hint is highly appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like an extremely complicated solution to a simple problem. What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: It is actually a complicated problem. I am trying to develop a tool to dynamically distribute a JEE Web application across two machines where distribution boundaries are identified based on the amount of data exchanged between classes of an initially monolithic JEE app. This is more of a research problem and I am aware of the simpler alternatives; but somehow curious whether what I have in mind will work. In theory I should be able to distribute every Java class through RMI after applying enough abstractions and serialization. My aim is to practice the theory in my solution.

Comment: well, i'm not going to pass judgement on what you are trying to do.  i will however, point out that you will need to be able to remote proxy streams (reqest and response both work with streams).  you should check out the rmiio project, which will enable you to use streams over rmi.

Comment: I see, that explains a lot. Sorry for my scepticism but without context your question looked a bit overcomplicated.

Comment: @biziclop I agree. sorry for not giving enough background on it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to make the remote interface implement Servlet.  instead, just mimic the methods in the remote interface.  then write a little servlet stub class which delegates all the calls to the remote proxy.  obviously, you'll need to wrap the RemoteExceptions in some other exception which can be thrown from the Servlet methods.

if you want to do this in a generic fashion, then you can probably implement a java.lang.Proxy handler which does the delegation for you (matching the Servlet interface methods with the relevant Remote versions).

Comment: Thanks @jtahlborn. I came to a similar conclusion having the problem discussed with a colleague. will try it either tonight or tomorrow and come back ... ;)

Comment: Actually, if you're using a dynamic proxy, you can implement the Servlet interface. What you don't have to implement is the Remote interface, as the invocation handler can take care of all the remote operations.

Comment: @bizicolp  thanks for the extra hints. I am just getting my feet wet with it. will report on the success here.